# OpenCV resizing the original video?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

So I've been working on a program to trim an input video to a specified time. For example, if a video is 3 minutes long, and I input numbers 20 and 30, it should output a video that is only 10 seconds long and has frames from 20th second up to 30th second.
The problem is that I have been using

`int width = capture.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);`

`int height = capture.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);`

but with some weird results.

In the properties of the output video it says that it is indeed the same width and height but when you watch the video, it isn't. It has black bars on the sides. It's like it's trying to fill the missing space, when there should be none.. ?

If anyone has an idea, it would be appreciated.

Comment: It's because those properties work with the camera, but I think it is not working with a movie file. Try resize instead

Comment: You are trying to change camera spec with those lines.  As @thibsc said resize is what you need. But of course resolution ll be lost

Comment: Can you explain in more detail on an example how that would be used ?

Comment: Are you trying to resize the dimensions of the video? Or are you just trying to cut out a piece of the original video without resizing it?